# Insert output value from stored procedure to a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a table storing stored procedure. I have nearly 50 different values to be entered into stored procedure so I have created a table to execute them catching the value from db itself. Below is the process I am using.

```
DECLARE @spvariable varchar(max);
SELECT @spvariable = e.ExecutionQuery FROM dbo.tmpsptable e where e.ID = @cnt;
Exec @spvariable;
```

In the stored procedure I have a value which returns after execution of each stored procedure, means there is a select statement at the end of SP with SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Each values are unique of course. Now the question is, for each execution,  I wanted to store the returned value in my table tmpsptable. But how do I call that and save on a specific row?

Openrowset is blocked to use it on my server. I cannot add insert statement into that same SP as it is used for other purposes as well.

Below is the one I am trying. I know using OUTPUT parameter is wrong in this case. But what can be the solution??

```
DECLARE @spvariable VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @insertedId TABLE(id INT);
DECLARE @cnt INT= 1;
WHILE @cnt <= 10
    BEGIN
       SELECT @spvariable = e.ExecutionQuery FROM dbo.tmpsptable e where e.ID = @cnt;
       EXEC @spvariable;  
        OUTPUT INSERTED.SerialNumber
        INTO @insertedId;

       UPDATE e
          SET
              SerialNumber = @insertedId
        FROM dbo.tmpsptable e
        WHERE e.ID = @cnt;
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END;
```

Comment: You need to stop using the NOLOCK hint in your updates immediately if not sooner. That query hint in an update can corrupt your indexes. I suspect you need to read a bit about that hint. It has some really nasty side effects. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Sorry that was from my select statement and I pasted it without removing NOLOCK. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: This question is not very clear to me. Are you storing a query in your table and then pulling it out and executing as dynamic sql? This is not a good way to handle data. So each row in tmpsptable has a query and you assume they are all the same? I am guessing so since they all call a stored procedure. There is something very off in the design here. What is that procedure doing?

Comment: @SeanLange Table stores all the variables needed to insert in Exec.... then i just need to call that column to execute

Comment: As I said before storing the code to call a stored procedure in a single column like this is not a great idea. But whatever, that is your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, the you want to use the [INSERT..EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) syntax.  There are a number of limitations, but it should probably work for you:

```
DECLARE @spvariable VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @id INT;
--DECLARE @insertedId TABLE(id INT);
-- you cannot INSERT from an EXEC into a @table variable
CREATE TABLE #insertedId(id INT);

DECLARE @cnt INT= 1;
WHILE @cnt <= 10
    BEGIN
       SELECT @spvariable = e.ExecutionQuery FROM dbo.tmpsptable e where e.ID = @cnt;

       DELETE FROM #instertedId;
       -- NOTE: the EXEC Result Set must exactly match the column types
       INSERT INTO #insertedId
       EXEC @spvariable;

       UPDATE e
          SET
              SerialNumber = (Select TOP 1 id From #insertedId)
        FROM dbo.tmpsptable e
        WHERE e.ID = @cnt;
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. You made a small type fixed in my query as well `(Select TOP 1 **id** From #insertedId)` Appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

`I know using OUTPUT parameter is wrong` - why?

If you are using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` then this is always a single row created per SP call, then you surely may return this scalar value as output parameter:

```
EXEC @spvariable
  @newID = @newID output
```

but in general I don't like your approach. `WHILE`, single-row SPs...

Comment: Returnning the value is not the issue. Using that returened value and insert into table.